# Give access only for a period of time

Tags: plugins

I'm new to WordPress and I need to sell a digital, non-downloadable product. I found WooCommerce plugin, I think it's useful. 
The problem is that I want to give access for **a period of time**.

This is a concrete example: 
Lets say the site is selling videos.
There are three types of subscriptions: 1 month, 6 months and 1 year.

Depending on the choice of the user, the site choose the access period **from the purchase date**.

If it's possible free solutions are better.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress StackExchange! Unfortunately, questions exclusively regarding 3rd party plugins is [considered to be off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and better asked using their respective support methods. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A membership plugin would be better for that, you can select content for each membership types as well. Try out https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/, it might solve your issue

Comment: Can I test payment using paypal **sandbox**?

Comment: There are multiple payment options, including paypal sandbox

Comment: plugin recommendation is not an answer, unless you are going to also explain how to use it

Comment: @MarkKaplun Ok...i will keep that in mind for the future